# 2d matrix to vector

Tags: java, matrix

In case:2 I should to convert 2d lower triangle matric to vector, but no results, it show only diognal. 
I tried many versions.
For example, I have random matrix:

> 1  0  0
>
> 7  5  0
>
> 8  2  9

So, I need:

> 1  7  5  8  2  9

Any help, please???

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ld {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A[][] = new int [10][10];   // Matricas inicializaacija
    int B[] = new int [55];         // Vektora inicializaacija
    int C[] = new int [10];         // Vektora inicializaacija
    int D[] = new int [10];         // Vektora inicializaacija
    boolean mat = false;            // Mainiigaa mat defineesana ar staavokli false
    boolean arr = false;            // Mainiigaa arr defineesana ar staavokli false
    int searchKey;                  // Mainiigaa searchKey defineesana
    int  a, i, j, c = 0;
    String st;
    Ld insertion = new Ld();
    Ld selection = new Ld();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    System.out.println("Paula Plauča RDBF09 151RDB331");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Izvada izveelni
        System.out.println("Masiva aizpildisana ar gadijuma vertibam     : 1");
        System.out.println("Masiva homogenu vertibu ierakstisana vektora : 2");
        System.out.println("Vektora elementa lineara algoritma meklesana : 3");
        System.out.println("Vektora skirosana ar iesprausanu (Insertion) : 4");
        System.out.println("Ja velaties iziet no sistemas nospiediet     : 0");

    boolean quit = false;           // Mainiigaa quit defineesana ar staavokli false
    int menuItem;
    do {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Izvelieties saskarnes vertibu : ");
          menuItem = in.nextInt();          // Mainiigajam menuItem pieskir case veertiibu skaitu
          switch (menuItem) {
        // Izveelnes pirmaa punkta realizaacija. Matricas aizpildisana ar patvaliigaam veertiibaam
          case 1:
            for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
                for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
                     if (j<=i) {
                        A[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
                     }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

            for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<=9; j++)
                    System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
                System.out.println();
            } mat = true;
                break;
        // Izveelnes otraa punkta realizaacija. Vektora aizpildisana ar patvaliigaam veertiibaam
          case 2:
            if (!mat){
                System.out.println("Sakuma nepieciesams izveidot masivu");
                continue;
            }
            for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
                for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
                     if (j<=i) {
                        B[i] = A[i][j];
                     }
            System.out.print("Iegutais vektors ir  :   ");
            for(int i1 = 0; i1 < B.length; i1++){
                    System.out.print(B[i1] + " ");
            } arr = true;
            System.out.println();
            break;

           // Pabeigt progammas darbiibu
          case 0:
            quit = true;
            break;                    
          default:
                System.out.println("Ievadita nepienemama vertiba.");
          }
    } while (!quit);
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the following code:

```
for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
    for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
        if (j<=i) {
            B[i] = A[i][j];
        }
```

The inner loop keeps overwriting the same location `B[i]`, so only the last value copied (where j==i) is retained.

You want something more like:

```
int k=0;
for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<=9; j++) {
        if (j<=i) {
            B[k++] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New problem with Insertion Sort: